# How to construct a JSON object from multi-word (space-separated) bash variables?

Tags: bash, json, jq

I have a small bash script that uses jq to construct a JSON object from user input. Unfortunately, I am unable to convince jq to accept a multi word variable as a value to one of its keys.

Here is an equivalent example from the bash prompt:

With no blank spaces jq  works as I expected:

```
$> value="Input"
$> jq -n --arg value $value '{"key": ($value)}'
```

returns:

```
{
   "key": "Input"
}
```

But it breaks with a multi-word value:

```
$> value="A multi word input"
$> jq -n --arg value $value '{"key": ($value)}'
```

returns an error:

```
jq: error: multi/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
multi
jq: 1 compile error
```

What's the magic that will convince jq not to choke on the white space of $value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unquoted `$value` is subject to word splitting by the shell - the answer is simply to quote it:

```
$ jq -n --arg value "$value" '{"key": ($value)}'
{
  "key": "A multi word input"
}
```

See also

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)